# What is the need of new Keyword in Method Hiding?

Tags: c#

I have two classes, named `base` and `derived` with *same method* name and *signature* suppose **M1** then, if I create an instance of the `derived` class and access the **M1** method so `derived` class **M1** will be called as an output with warning **use new keyword if method hiding was intended** and if I put a `new` keyword in the `derived` class still **M1** method of the *derived* class will be called as an output but this time without the warning. So if we got the same response without a `new` keyword and still method hiding is done so what is the need to use a `new` keyword?

Comment: Code is better and less ambiguous than a story

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords

Answer (score 4):

The warning exists to remind the programmer to clarify their intent by using either `new` or `override`. If you really intend to hide the base method, use `new` and the warning goes away. Or if you meant to actually override the base method, then thank the compiler for pointing out the error and use `override`.

Comment: So this means for removing the warning we need to put new keyword?

Comment: Yes, this is the only purpose, this helps when you are working in a big team, then everybody knows what is intent or what is not, programmatically.